# Asynchronous POST endpoint awaits an asynchronous method that does not have "AWAIT" on it but GET does not (C#/JS)

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have an asynchronous endpoint. It calls an asynchronous method inside but does not have "AWAIT" on it.

This is using C# for backend and using jQuery to call it.

When I set this endpoint as POST, it returns only once the method inside are done executing.

When I set this endpoint as GET, it returns immediately without waiting for the method inside to be done. Which is what I wanted in the first place.

Appreciate the response! Thanks!

Example endpoint code

```
    [HttpPost] //[HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> DownloadPubSubListener()
    {
            NotificationListenerAsync(); // without AWAIT
                
            return Json("success");
    }
    
    private async Task NotificationListenerAsync()
    {
            await notif.BrokerConfig();
    }
```

Comment: Don't talk about code, include a minimal example.

Comment: I apologize. I updated it @JeremyLakeman